# iphone daemon NSTimer interval when in standby mode

Tags: iphone, nstimer, daemon, nstimeinterval

```
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date] interval:60 target:manager selector:@selector(queryServer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

I use code above in my daemon app to do something every one minute, but if iphone enter standby mode,  timer won't run every one minute . So what should I do to make timer run every one minute when iphone is in standby mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way that I can run something every 1 hour even iphone is in standby mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer does not work in deep sleep mode, but you can make it work by setting the idleTimerDisabled property to TRUE, but remember, if you do this, battery will be utilized more.

Comment: [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled=YES;

Comment: [UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled=YES; My app is a daemon, and [UIApplication sharedApplication] is nil. Besides NSTimer, can I use some other api to finish the function. Thank you;

Comment: Somebody else play silent background music to prevent iphone in deep sleep mode. I am not sure if I should do so, thank you

Comment: Hello dustdn, how did you solve this? i'm having same problem.